# How can I install a jenkins plugin that is not listed?

Tags: cloudbees

I want to use a plugin that is not listed under the list of available plugins. I know how can I do this in my local Jenkins but not in cloudbees.

http://pocketsoap.com/weblog/2011/02/1849.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

FREE and Base subscription don't let you get jenkins plugins but the ["essential" list](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/EssentialsPlugins) you see on update center. For Pro and Enterprise subscription you can ask support to install such plugins if they're not already available in update center (that only deliver pre-tested plugins).